# Subdomains permalinks issues

Tags: subdomains

I am using **Main Category As Subdomain plugin** for subdomains but getting some issues

**it is giving this type urls**: (news.fashionforwarddaily.com/news/events-news/prgmea-inks-deal-to-organize-international-textile-asia-exhibition/)

But i need this type ulrs: (news.fashionforwarddaily.com/events-news/prgmea-inks-deal-to-organize-international-textile-asia-exhibition/)

**Note: it is repeating news two time i.e duplicate please give me solutions**

Thanks
D.Nayak

Answer (score 1):

first i would read [other peoples solutions in the plugin support section](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/main-category-as-subdomain). next i would completely disable sef generation in settings > permalinks. last advice: do not develop on a production site, instead set up a local dev environment.